# Java specify default

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

I'm trying to create a factory class to decide at runtime what needs to be injected.

I created a Producer Factory:

```
public class AuthorizationServiceFactory {

    @Inject
    private AuthorizationServiceImpl authorizationService;

    @Produces
    public AuthorizationService getService() {
        //decide here
    }
}
```

Authorization service is an interface:

```
public interface AuthorizationService {
    //methods here
}
```

And I have only one implementation to the interface (I plan to have more, but I am simplifying to make it work):

```
public class AuthorizationServiceImpl implements AuthorizationService {
    //implementation here
}
```

In my other class, I try to inject, like this:

```
@Inject
protected AuthorizationService authorizationService;
```

It gives me a `Ambiguous dependencies for type [AuthorizationService] with qualifiers [@Any] at injection point blablabla...`

I realized that it has two possibilities, the Producer factory and the Implmentation itself. I tryed to annotate the factory method with @Default and the other class with @Alternative, but then I need to inject a AuthorizationServiceImpl in the factory and it says it is not active for injection.

```
Unsatisfied dependencies for type [AuthorizationServiceImpl] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point blablabla...
```

Is there any way to specify that the factory method is how it produce the interface and still be able to inject a instance so the factory return it without creating some annotations interfaces?

Some more info, I'm actually doing this because I want the factory method to produce the proper AuthorizationService based on a database vaue.

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on CDI Alternatives, which does exactly what you're looking for without the need for factories.  You essentially introduce an "Alternate" qualifier that describes the non-default implementations and allow someone to activate that in beans.xml.

Comment: I would like to choose the alternative based on system toggles (either in the DB or in a properties file) without changing the packaged application.

Comment: Then perhaps you need to try using qualifiers to qualify all instances of the injected bean.